# Wire grid polarizer dimension

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Why should the space between the wires be less than the wavelength of radiation in order for the polarizer to work efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a heuristic interpretation of what is happening.
Taking a classical view of the electromagnetic field. For the wire grid polarizer any incident electromagnetic wave's electric field can be decomposed into a component perpendicular to the wires and parallel to the wires. For a wire grid polarizer you are counting on the grid to transmit the perpendicular polarization and reflect or absorb the parallel polarization.

The polarization perpendicular to the wires should be transmitted regardless of the spacing given that the wires themselves have a small enough diameter. This is because currents cannot be excited orthogonal to the wires so this component of the electric field won't interact strongly with the polarizer.

For the component that is polarized parallel to the wires, currents will be excited and the field will interact with the wires. The forward scattered fields of the current will cancel the incident field and the reverse scattered fields will show up as the reflected field. How strongly the field interacts with the polarizer as a whole depends on the spacing of the wires though.

If you consider the gaps in the wires independently then they appear like apertures. With an aperture larger than a wavelength significant diffraction will occur and the parallel polarization will leak through. Increasing the transmitted power of the parallel polarized field. Noting that the transmitted fields power is proportional $T$ where, $T=1-|\Gamma|^2$. If $T$ increases then $|\Gamma|$ has decreased so less of the parallel polarized field has been reflected. Therefore, if you want to efficiently polarize the field the wire grid should have a spacing less than a wavelength to limit the amount of the parallel polarized field that diffracts through.

Comment: From what I know the diffraction (which is responsible for the bending of light past the geometrical shadow) at least in the sigle slit case,  is mostly accentuated for small apertures.

Comment: This is true in the sense that an incident plane wave will be spread out more with a smaller aperture, such that it will appear like a radially spreading source with a pinhole. However, the amount of power that will propagate through the aperture will decrease when compared to a larger aperture.

Comment: @Ijs In this case, both the parallel and the perpendicular component of the electric field would penetrate through the aperture. True, some amount of the parallel component would be reflected form the wires.

Comment: @nikoschatziathanasiou Yes, so if the aperture were large less of the parallel component would be reflected and the emerging light would appear to be unpolarized. For a smaller aperture less light would pass through and the emerging light would appear to be polarized.

Comment: @Ijs I guess, this now makes sense...But why do we say that the space between the wires should be less than a wavelength and not the smallest possible so as to block the penetration?

Comment: @nikoschatziathanasiou If  you are interested in digging into it a little more I found [this](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/polarizer.pdf) source with a good explanation of the math.

Comment: @nikoschatziathanasiou It comes down to the diffraction limit. Less than half a wavelength should be ideal because below that the wave cannot resolve the individual apertures and it essentially looks like a solid reflector. Less than a wavelength is enough to significantly limit the transmitted power though.